# Manually adding Chatter

Tags: chatter

Has anyone tried managing chatter with JavaScrip? I have a page that is rendered with Ajax calls into my controller. The thing is that it never does a post back to the server to get rendered content. It is all rendered with JavaScript.

I'd like to add Chatter for a record retrieved in the Ajax response but since the page does not do a post back and the  component requires the entityId in order to be rendered, I'd have to come up with a way for the JavaScipt to create/enable the chatter section for the retrieved object.

Has anyone done this?
If so what are things to watch?